# Run Chromeless headless more than once

Tags: javascript, chromeless

I have tried to run my Chromeless script headlessly more than once.

I start by launching Chrome according to the doc (https://github.com/prisma/chromeless#local-chrome-usage):

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application"
chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --disable-gpu --headless
```

then in a different terminal, with launchChrome: false:

```
node my_script.js
```

it works, but if I try to launch my script a second time, I get a timeout error on the first "wait" command.

I guess it's related to the Chrome process still running, but I have no idea how to kill it either.

What's the proper way to run a Chromeless script headless multiple times on Windows?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the `--user-data-dir`?

Comment: @Brad you mean after the `chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --disable-gpu --headless` command? What would this change, especially knowing the script worked the first time I tried to launch it?